# Validating numeric input with perl regex

Tags: regex, perl, validating

I'm having difficulty validating user input with my regex. I'm trying to take user input and make sure it's between 1 and 99. If it's not then it calls the same sub-routine until a validating entry is matched. However, even if the input is between 1-99 it will keep calling the sub routine.

```
sub get_age
{
    print "Age :";
    @get_age = <STDIN>;
    if (scalar @get_age  !~ m/\d[1-99]/ ) #making sure age given is between 1 and 99
    {

            print "ERROR, invalid input\n";
            &get_age; #this is callng the same sub it's in to re-run validating
    }

            push(@get_age, <STDIN>); #taking name from user and putting it in @get_name     array
            chomp(@get_age); #erasing newline from input
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with a simple `if` condition to test `>1` and `<99`?

Comment: @Cratylus: The problem with it is a pair of off-by one errors... He'd want to test for >=1 and <=99.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be confused about

1. What the `@` sigil does in Perl,
2. How character classes in regexes work,
3. What context in Perl is
4. How the readline operator `<...>` behaves depending on context.
5. (Why you should never do `&foo`).

#### The `@` sigil

The `@` denotes an array. This imposes *list context* on the right hand side of an assignment.

#### Character classes

A character class is denoted by square brackets, and can include ranges of characters, e.g. `[0-9]` — match the arabic digits. The `\d` named character class matches many more characters — whatever Unicode considers "numeric".

A character class can be negated with a leading caret. E.g. `[^0-9]` matches any character that is not an arabic digit.

#### Context

Perl operators behave differently depending on context. For example the readline operator:

- In *scalar context* (singular), the readline operator reads a single line, but
- in *list context* (plural), the readline operator reads all lines until the end of file (EOF) is encountered. To send the EOF on keyboard input, you usually use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>.

When an `@array` is encountered, it evaluates to the list of all elements, in list context. However, in scalar context, it evaluates to the *length* of the array.

#### What `@get_age = <STDIN>` does

Because the LHS is an array, the RHS is evaluated in list context. As explained above, this reads input until the stream is exhausted. Each element in `@get_age` holds one line of the input after the assignment.

#### What `scalar @get_age  !~ m/\d[1-99]/` does

This expression is similar to

```
my $length = scalar @get_age;
not $length =~ /\d[1-9]/;
```

I.e. the array in scalar context evaluates to the length of the array, which is the number of lines in the input.

The regex says *“Inside the string, there must be one unicode numeric character followed by either 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9”*. Multiple occurrences of a character in a charclass are discarded. The string may include arbitrary other characters. This should match: `"my age is 020!"`

#### What you probably wanted to do:

```
sub get_age {
  print "Age: ";
  my $age = <STDIN>; # scalar context, and put into a private variable
  chomp $age;        # remove newline
  if( not length $age ) { # check for empty string
    say "You didn't type anything. Retry!";
    return get_age();
  }
  if( $age =~ /[^0-9]/ ) { # recurse on any non-digits
    say "You typed non-numeric characters. Restrict yourself to '0' through '9'. Retry!";
    return get_age();
  }
  unless( 1 <= $age && $age <= 99 ) { # check for correct bounds
    say "Valid ages have to be in the range 1 to 99. Retry!";
    return get_age();
  }
  return $age;
}
```

Then in your main code:

```
my $age = get_age();
```

Comment: +1 Love long answers :)  1. Might avoid the recursion and iterate in a loop  2. Why mix `&&` and `or` ?

Comment: @Andomar: re: #2, operator precedence. `&&`/`||` bind relatively tightly (have high precedence), so they're best used for logical operations. `and`/`or` bind extremely loosely (low precedence), so they're good for flow control. Basically, mixing them this way helps to ensure that it doesn't get parsed as `1 <= $age && ($age <= 99 || return)`.

Comment: a regex wouldn't have allowed non-integers; I'd guess that isn't a desired feature in your code.

Comment: @ysth You are absolutely correct, the updated code should now cover all cases.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to list all of this. I am trying to get more practice with regular expressions however, which is why I didn't go through the standard approach of `age > 0 && age < 99`

Comment: Instead of `return get_age();` it might be a good idea to put the entire thing in a bare block and call [`redo`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/redo.html "perldoc -f redo"). You could also use [`goto __SUB__;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/__SUB__.html "perldoc -f \_\_SUB\_\_") ( [`goto &get_age;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/goto.html "perldoc -f goto") prior to 5.16 ) Another option is `recur` from [Sub::Call::Recur](http://p3rl.org/Sub::Call::Recur).

Comment: @BradGilbert RE: “a good idea”. I do love a good tail recursion optimization, but this isn't the place for it: *(1)* It has nothing to do with input validation, *(2)* The function will spend far more time blocking on user input than allocating memory for the call stack or executing a chain of returns. *(3)* The user would have to do ~100 invalid entries before the “deep recursion” warning turns up. I do hope anyone could do better than that ;-) (I actually considered such optimizations while writing my answer, but *decided* against them. Premature optimization, the root of all evil, and stuff)

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.012;
use strict; use warnings;
use Term::Prompt qw( prompt );

my $age = prompt(s => 'Age:', 'between 1 and 99', '', sub {
        my ($input) = @_;
        ($input) = ($input =~ /\A\s*( [1-9] [0-9]? )\s*\z/x);
        return $input and ($input >= 1) and ($input <= 99);
    }
);

say $age;
```

Answer (score 1):

`[1-99]` is the set of all characters from 1 to 9 and the character 9.

Try `[1-9]|([1-9]\d)` instead.  That means either 1-9 or any two numbers not starting with a zero.

Comment: and what about 20, 30, 40, ... ?

Comment: @MiguelPrz: `[1-9]\d` matches 20, 30 and 40.  And 50 too.

Comment: sorry, I didn't see the \d

Comment: and 1-watermelon (1).  if you mean `[0-9]` say it, not \d (or in 5.14+ use the /a flag)

Comment: If you want to only match 0..9 you should specify it; otherwise you **will** match more than you want `perl -E'no warnings;for("\x{FF11}","\x{1D7CF}","\x{1D7D9}","\x{1D7E3}","\x{1D7ED}","\x{1D7F7}","\x{0967}"){say if /^\d$/}'`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an improved version of your code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub get_age_and_name
{
    my $age;
    while(1) {
        print "Age : ";
        $age = <STDIN>;
        chomp $age;
        # Making sure age given is between 1 and 99
        last if( $age =~ m/^\d\d?$/ and ($age>=1) and($age<=99) );
        print "Error ERROR, invalid input\n";
    } 

    print "Name : ";
    my $name = <STDIN>;
    chomp $name;
    return ($age, $name);
}


my ($age, $name) = get_age_and_name;
print "($age, $name)\n";
```

Comment: Instead of `while(1){...;last if ...; print "error"}`, how about `{...;if( !... ){ print "error"; redo}}`

Comment: because TIMTOWTDI,... I've used what it's more readable for me ;)